# How to set access-control-allow-origin even for 404 with HapiJs?

Tags: node.js, cors, hapi.js

I have my HapiJS server configured as :

```
const server = Hapi.server({
    host: env.HOSTNAME,
    port: env.PORT,
    routes :
        {
            cors: {
                origin: ['ignore'],
                headers: ['Accept', 'Authorization', 'Content-Type'],
            }
        }
});
```

Example of a route : 
`GET /api/v3/users { cors: { origin: 'ignore', headers: [ '*' ] },
  validate: { query: { token: [Object] } } }`

If I request it directly from the browser, or postman I get the following return :

[image: Network image from chrome]

So I can see the `access-control-allow-origin: *` header is set.

---

But when I ask this resource from `react` with an `XHR Request`, I get a 404 on the `OPTIONS` request and then a CORS Error such as :

[image]

So i get a CORS error.

How to set `access-control-allow-origin` even for `404` with HapiJs ?

Comment: Do you get any solution for this. please let me know.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find a solution directly through NodeJS.
So I used a Nginx reverse-proxy server as the web front door.

Comment: I did the same :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately i didn't find any solution directly through NodeJS as I don't think there is.

So I used a Nginx reverse-proxy server as the web front door always giving the right Headers.